# What prevents me to create an Google Play in-app product?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app

I have at "In-app products" of Google Play Console:

> To add in-app products, you need to add the BILLING permission to your APK

I uploaded a bundle for both internal and closed testing and they were reviewed. I do have BILLING permission. What prevents me to create an in-app product?

Answer (score 1):

I by mistake wrote `android.permission.BILLING` instead of correct `com.android.vending.BILLING`.